# Bulk create folders based on image names

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe, executable

I have lots of product images which are named similar to

- ABC-image-main
- ABC-image-1
- ABC-image-2
- BCD-image-main
- BCD-image-1

Etc.

All the images are in 1 folder currently. I have all the image names on excel/word.

What I'm looking to do is create an executable which will auto create the sub folders for the images and to cut the images across into. E.g. on this example, there would be 2 folders called "ABC" and "BCD"

I have figured out how to bulk create folders but not sure how to get the images into those folders automatically.

Any help would be appreciated or even pointing in the right direction for me to look into.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directories are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.jpg" ') DO (
 FOR /f "delims=-" %%y IN ("%%e") DO (
  ECHO MD "%destdir%\%%y" 2>nul
  ECHO move "%sourcedir%\%%e" "%destdir%\%%y"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Similar questions have been asked many times before.

Obtain a directory-list of filesnames only (no directorynames) and assign each filename in turn to `%%e`. I've assued that hese are `.jpg` files; if there is more than one type, simply repeat `"%sourcedir%\*.jpg"` with the other filename-masks as required.

Examine `%%e` and extract the part before the `-` to `%%y`.

Create the destination directory.

Move the file.

See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation - or thousands of examples on SO.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)